# Importing List from antoher File in Python

Tags: python, list, import

I have 2 files in the same directory:

func.py:

```
import openpyxl

def openText():
 wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/Users/*****/*****/****/****/*****/main/Sentences.xlsx')
 sheet = wb["Sheet1"]
 i = 2
 Text = []
 Row = sheet[f'A{i}'].value

 while Row != None:
       Text.append(Row)
       i += 1
       Row = sheet[f'A{i}'].value
 return Text
```

main.py:

```
from func import Text
from func import openText

openText()

print[Text]
```

The Text list should be imported, but I get this error:

```
cannot import name 'Text' from 'func'
```

Comment: Text is an object inside the scope of the `openText` function, so you cannot access it outside that scope.

Comment: `Text` is local to `openText` and is not visible outside it, not even elsewhere in `func.py`. And that is as it should be.  Do `print(openText())`, with `( )` not `[ ]`,  to output the returned result of the function.

Answer (score -1):

Declare `Text` globally in `func.py` file. Inside the method add this statement `global Text`.

```
import openpyxl
Text = []
def openText():
 wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('/Users/*****/*****/****/****/*****/main/Sentences.xlsx')
 sheet = wb["Sheet1"]
 i = 2
 Row = sheet[f'A{i}'].value
 global Text
 while Row != None:
       Text.append(Row)
       i += 1
       Row = sheet[f'A{i}'].value
 return Text
```

In the `main.py` file, call `openText` and you'll get the same `Text` from the `func.py` file:

```
from func import Text
from func import openText

x=openText()

print(x)
```

Comment: There is no need to make `Text` global. The function returns its value. All OP has to do is output that returned value or save it in a variable instead of throwing it away. Doing as you suggest will fix the problem but it won't help OP's fundamental misunderstanding of how functions work.

Comment: I know this is not a good programming practice. Depending on the code OP shared, what's the point of importing `Text` from another file? Some other method/code segment might be manipulating this list? Thanks anyways!